# How would I track one person liked something? For instance a video

Tags: php, algorithm, laravel

Say for instance you are tracking whether or not a person has Liked a video.
If you're logged in well, that's easy enough, when you like a video add a new row in your table with that userId.

The problem arises when you try to track anonymous person.
I tried to approaches.

1. by ip:
   works kinda OK, but the problem is that if you send a video to 100 people inside the same building you can only like it once as all of them have the same IP
2. by session:
   works kinda OK too but every time you close the browser a new session is created therefore you can spam-like if you keep doing this (honestly this is the lesser of the problems)

right now I'm going with the session solution but I wonder if there's a better/easier way?

Comment: Not really, you can pass a cookie but  user can delete it. HTTP[s] is stateless. Not much you can do with it.

Comment: have you tried cookies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Laravel. I'd probably approach this using the session class, more specifically `memcached` or `redis`, I prefer the latter. Store session with vid id and check for the session when rendering view, let it expire after a day or a few hours or never. If it exists, re-create - if not, do null.

`redis` will also allow you to make more fine tuned queries. For example, to see how many views a video has, etc. But something like this may be more appropriate in database form.

Answer (score -1):

You can check user by MAC address.

```
<?
ob_start();
system('ipconfig /all');
$mycom=ob_get_contents();
ob_clean();

$findme = "Physical";
$pmac = strpos($mycom, $findme);
$mac=substr($mycom,($pmac+36),17);

echo $mac;
?>
```

Comment: Interesting. Isn't MAC address of router though - not machine?

Comment: most likely that will do nothing as most servers forbid 'system` calls. but even if it did... it would just result with the server's NIC MAC and not the client's